# У меня стоит задача написать бот

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cors, бот

Всем привет.
Стоит задача.
Нужно при событии клик, отправить запрос с сайта Х на сайт У, авторизоваться, перейти на нужную страницу, вытянуть данные из html разметки и отправить данные назад на сайт Х.

1. Можно ли такое реализовать?
2. Какие инструменты лучше использовать для решения такой задачи?
3. Где можно посмотреть выполнение подобной задачи на примерах?
4. Куда копать в конце концов! :) Что смотреть, читать.(на русском желательно).

Что у меня:
`js`, немного знаком c `node.js` `ajax` `CORS`.

Знающих прошу направить на путь истинный.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправляете запрос себе на node.js, там делаете запрос на авторизацию, запрос на нужную страницу, парсите её и отдаете назад

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но сильно обобщенно. Не могли бы вы на примере то же самое описать?
То есть нужен сервер на node? Просто со страницы сайта Х такую манипуляцию нельзя сделать?

Comment: Просто со страницы может и можно, но очень неудобно. Вот вам в помощь [парсер html для ноды](https://cheerio.js.org/) и [модуль, чтобы делать запросы](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: Вам нужно будет пойти на сайт Y, открыть там консоль на вкладке Netwrok, посмотреть как происходит авторизация, и воспроизвести нужный запрос.

Comment: @АлександрИщенко Почитайте этот цикл статей https://habrahabr.ru/post/301426/

Comment: Спасибо тем кто откликнулся.