# Как написать бот для браузера?

Tags: c++, python, веб-программирование, бот

Здравствуйте! 
Появилась вот потребность в автоматизации действий в браузере. По сути требуется, чтобы бот мог находить элемент на странице, обновлять страницу и просто мог нажимать на кнопки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может помочь в реализации такой идеи с ботом.
Сам я учусь в институте и обладаю поверхностными знаниями в С++ и Python.

Comment: Делал как-то бота для браузерной игры: https://github.com/gil9red/moswar_bot если игра еще жива, аккаунт не удален, то при запуске бот сразу начнет играть

Comment: Я так понял, что это образец, с которого мне надо брать пример. Но я совсем профан. Опишите, пожалуйста, поподробнее, что к чему, или скиньте литературу/сайт, где можно про это почитать.

Comment: Установить питон 3.4 (библиотека PySide вроде бы после 3.4 версии не поддерживается), установить pyside, запустить main.py после чего откроется окно бота, и тот авторизуется в игру и начнет выполнять рутинные задания: игра в наперстки, нападение на врагов и т.п. А насчет разбирательств... python, javascript, html, Qt, QWebView, css-селекторы . Вот набор технологий, что бот использует

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683516/У-меня-стоит-задача-написать-бот?rq=1

Comment: Используй Selenium.